# PhantomJS error: Cannot access member 'write' of deleted QObject

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I need to create web api on port 7788 which will accept json, then pass that json to my api which will render website, and then phantom js will find element on that page and web api on port 7788 should return that element. Everything's go well till moment I try to send reponse to my server on 7788, error:

> cannot access member `write' of deleted QObject:

for this: `firstResponse.write(imgsrc);`

Is it possible to return element with server.listen response after page.open is called?

```
var server = require('webserver').create();
    var port = require('system').env.PORT || 7788;

    server.listen(port, {'keepAlive': false}, function (request, response) {

        console.log("request method: ", request.method);  // request.method POST or GET    
            var imgsrc;
            var firstResponse = response;

        if (request.method == 'POST') {

            var page = require('webpage').create();
            var settings = {
              operation: "POST",
              encoding: "utf8",
              headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
              },
              data: JSON.stringify(request.post)
            };
            var url = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/mapapp";

             page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg, lineNum, sourceId) {
                console.log('CONSOLE: ' + msg + ' (from line #' + lineNum + ' in "' + sourceId + '")');
            }; 

            page.open(url, settings, function (status) {


                setTimeout(function () {
                    page.evaluate(function () { 

                        imgsrc = document.getElementById("exportedImg").src;
                    });

                }, 5000);
            });
            page.close();
            setTimeout(function () {
                    firstResponse.write(imgsrc);

                }, 7000);
        firstResponse.close(); 

        }


    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You call firstResponse.close(); before is called firstResponse.write(imgsrc); after your timeout.
Move firstResponse.close() to setTimeout handler:

```
page.close();
setTimeout(function () {
            firstResponse.write(imgsrc);
            firstResponse.close(); 
}, 7000);
```